Macaulay's use of "pigstyes" in his essay on Boswell's "Life of Johnson"
In Thomas Babington Macaulay's essay on Croker's edition of Boswell's Life of Johnson I found this (page 349):

The very page which contains this monstrous blunder, contains another blunder, if possible, more monstrous still. Sir Joseph Mawbey, a foolish member of Parliament, at whose speeches and whose pigstyes the wits of Brookes's were, fifty years ago, in the habit of laughing most unmercifully, stated, on the authority of Garrick, that Johnson, while sitting in a coffee-house at Oxford, about the time of his doctor's degree, used some contemptuous expressions respecting Home's play and Macpherson's Ossian.

I know that Brookes was a famous club, and I imagine the members thought they were wits, but I can't see their wanting to mock the poor man's literal pigstyes; was this a short-lived metaphor for some verbal blunder? Is it even a coinage of Macaulay's?

Macaulay means “pig-sties” literally. Joseph Mawbey (1730–1798) owned a distillery at Vauxhall in London; the process of distilling of spirits uses malted grain, and only a portion of this is converted to alcohol by the yeast, leaving a residue of mash that has to be disposed of. A common use of this “draff” is to feed livestock such as pigs. In an 1830 treatise on livestock farming, I find the following passage describing the decline in the number of pigs raised in this way in London:

Scarcely any bacon is now made in or near London, the Distillers, who formerly fed such great numbers of hogs, having long since exchanged that species of stock for bullocks; and subsequently, many of the houses have given up all live stock, disposing of their wash and grains to the cow-keepers. The starch-houses of the metropolis keep about four or five hundred hogs each, of which they make somewhat more than two annual returns, fat; or perhaps more, since a smaller and quicker feeding breed of pigs has come into use. These houses, in the year 1829, will have turned out nearly three thousand fat hogs. More than double that number were fattened in and near the metropolis, by six houses, upwards of half a century since, and before the revolutionary war with America. Of these, the great house at Lambeth, Stonard and Curtis, had room for nearly one thousand, and that of the late Mr. Suter, of the same place, the reputed quickest, cleanest, and best feeder in England, equally reputed for the quality of his stock, nearly five hundred. Cooper of Bow, one thousand. At the same period [the 1770s] the Distillers all fed hogs, Sir Joseph Mawbey, at Lambeth, having styes to contain two thousand.
Bonington Moubray (1830). A Practical Treatise on Breeding, Rearing, and Fattening All Kinds of Domestic Poultry, Pheasants, Pigeons, And Rabbits; Also the Management of Swine, Milch Cows, and Bees; and Instructions for the Private Brewery, pages 179–180. London:
Sherwood, Gilbert, and Piper.

So Mawbey owned pig-sties accommodating two thousand pigs, the sale of whose bacon was one of the sources of his fortune. He was satirized for this in the Rolliad (1785), which includes the lines:

A sty of pigs, though all at once it squeaks,
Means not so much as Mawbey when he speaks;
And hist’ry says, he never yet had bred
A pig with such a voice, or such a head!
Except, indeed, when he essays to joke;
And then his wit is truly pig-in-poke. […]
Such adaptation ne’er was seen before,
His trade a hog is, and his wit—a boar.
Anonymous (1785). Criticisms on the Rolliad, third edition, pages 155–156. London: James Ridgway.

The authors of the Rolliad included Richard FitzPatrick (1748–1813), who “frequented the pro-Whig club Almack's, which later became Brooks's” (Wikipedia). This explains Macaulay’s phrase “the wits of Brookes’s”.
Here’s a 1788 caricature by James Gillray, titled “A Pig in a Poke”, likely inspired by the lines quoted above. Mawbey (left) has two documents in his pocket, one labelled “Burn Justice”, the other “Surrey Commission”. His left-hand opponent, possibly representing Philip Francis (1740–1818), says “Oh! you’ve brought your Pigs to a fine Market!”

Wright and Evans say that “Burn Justice” alludes to the unsatisfactory outcome (for Mawbey) of a lawsuit brought against him by his steward:

Sir Joseph Mawbey having quarrelled with his steward, Wilkinson, claimed £30 as a balance due to him. The steward denied this, and Sir Joseph arrested him for it. He offered to release him on payment of £20, and afterwards for £10. Both sums being refused, he released him. Wilkinson then brought an action against him, and recovered £150 damages.† This oppressive transaction is probably alluded to in the inscription, “Burn justice,” and “you have brought your pigs to a fine market.”
Thomas Wright and R. H. Evans (1851). Historical and Descriptive Account of the Caricatures of James Gillray, page 27. London: Henry G. Bohn.
† The equivalent of roughly £20,000 today, according to the Bank of England inflation calculator.

The subtitle “Whist. Whist.” puns on whist, the card game, and “whisht”, a call “often used by farmers to calm livestock” (OED). “Surrey Commission” is presumably related to Mawbey’s activities in that county, where he was a landlord and sheriff, but I don’t know if there is a more specific reference.

Well I'll be damned — very interesting!
